# How to login user automatically in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using phone authentication using cloud firestore. In firestore db, I am storing user phone number and uid. Here is the code which, I have tried for mobile number login:

```
  @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {
    // dismiss keyboard
    view.endEditing(true)   
    if sendOTP == false {
    let mobileNumber = "+91" + phoneNumberTextField.text!

    self.Userdefaults.set(mobileNumber, forKey: "mobileNumber")

    print("mobileNumber::::\(mobileNumber)")

    sendOTPCode()
    sendOTP = true

    } else {

        let codestring = OTPCodeTextField.text

        if codestring?.count == 6 {


            loginusingOTP(OTPtext: codestring!)


        } else {

            print("Enter 6 digit code")

        }

    }


func sendOTPCode() {

    let mymobilenumber = Userdefaults.string(forKey: "mobileNumber")
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(mymobilenumber!) { (verificationID, error) in


            self.Userdefaults.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")

            if error != nil
            {
                print ("insde SendCode, there is error")



                print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

            } else {
                print ("code sent")


                self.phoneNumberTextField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false



            }
    }

}

func loginusingOTP(OTPtext: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let verificationID = self.Userdefaults.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")

    let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID!,
                                                                                  verificationCode: OTPtext)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
    {
        (user, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
        else if user != nil
        {

            print("Phone number: \(String(describing: user?.phoneNumber))")
            let userInfo = user?.providerData[0]
            print("Provider ID: \(String(describing: userInfo?.providerID))")

            var _: DocumentReference? = nil

            print("currentUser:::\(String(describing: currentUser))")

            db.collection("users").document(currentUser!).setData([
                "User_Phone_number": user?.phoneNumber as Any,
                "uid": currentUser as Any

            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                    if PrefsManager.sharedinstance.isFirstTime == false{


                        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpToTabBar", sender: nil)

                        }


                    }else{
                        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {


                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
                            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardvc")
                            self.present(initialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        }
                    }



                }
            }

        } else {

            print("error::::::")

        }

    }

}
```

User login flow - First user enter phone number and then taps on send otp then user enters otp code, logged in successfully. Since user login first time, user needs to fill user detail page and then goes to home page. If its already logged in user, after successful of login user will redirected to home screen not the user detail page.

My question is now user is login each and every time to get inside of the app, I want user to login automatically without login each and every time unless user logout. How to check already logged in user UID or phone in cloud firestore for user exist or new user.

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: you need to check for currently logged in user. If you find no user than take him to the login screen.

Comment: Once user is login you can set flag in `UserDefaults` and everyTime you need check if flag is true then redirect to HomeScreen( you need to  code in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` )otherwise default Login screen will open. and in logout you need to remove this flag value from  `UserDefaults`

Comment: are you done with the solution?

Comment: nope its not working @PPL

Comment: @PvDev what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 11):

Let me give you brief scenario.

[SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults) is the best library to store `UserDefaults` throughout the app.

Create one extension like this,

```
extension DefaultsKeys {
    static let username = DefaultsKey<String?>("username")
    static let phoneNo = DefaultsKey<String?>("phoneNo")
    static let islogin = DefaultsKey<Bool?>("islogin")
}
```

After successful login, you can set the values of the above `DefaultKeys` like below, first `import SwiftyUserDefaults`,

```
Defaults[.username] = Your_User_Name
Defaults[.phoneno] = Your_Phone_No
Defaults[.islogin] = true
```

Now on your first `LoginViewController`, in `viewDidLoad()` method, Please check following,

```
if Defaults[.islogin] == true {
    //Go to Home with animation false
}
```

Here you go, let me know in case of any queries.

**FYI**. This is just the scenario, actual may be different depending on your final requirement. This answer may help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!! need to install pod for swiftuserdefaults.. where should i pass Defaults[.username] = Your_User_Name
Defaults[.phoneno] = Your_Phone_No
Defaults[.islogin] = true this one

Comment: This is your data, I have taken three fields for just your info, if successful login, Your_Phone_No is the user entered phone no, islogin should be true

Comment: pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults', :git => "https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults.git" error installing pod

Comment: pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults' just do this

Answer (score 8):

For Firebase (and it looks like FireStore). Once the User is Authenticated on the device, they will automatically be "logged in" to Firebase/Firestore next sessions unless there is a specific SignOut (Auth.auth().signOut()) or unless there is a super long delay (not sure how long, maybe a month).

To check to see if the user is already logged in.

On Start Up (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) set up an Auth Listener and it will fire once and return the current Auth Status.

```
func addUserListener() {
    listenHandler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user == nil {
            // We are Logged Out of Firebase.
            // Move to Login Screen
        } else {
            // we are Logged In to Firebase.
            // Move to Main Screen
        }
  }
```

You really need to use an Auth Listener for Login calls as if someone has two devices and logs out on one device, they will be logged out of firebase and the 2nd device will crash when you try a firebase call, because it still thinks its logged in.

Comment: This is the more efficient, preferred, and the firebase way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Update your login credentials OR loggedIn flag to user Defaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "username")
UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "password")
```

*(NB: i recommended not to store password directly, you could store authentication token in Userdefaults, & if you want password to be stored, use keychain instead)*

And redirect to corresponding page from AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   var initialViewController: UIViewController?
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let username = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "username"), let password = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "password") {
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
    } else {
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
    }
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   return true
}
```

Comment: Please don't store user credentials in `UserDefaults`, rather put them into the keychain for security reasons.